# Python prints two times when there is only one print() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering why my code prints two same output even though I printed once.

I was trying to Read and Edit the .docx files using *python-docx* and *readDocx* modules in Python 3 from a book called Automate the boring stuff with Python by Al Sweigart.

The **demo.docx** contains these simple 6 text lines:

1. Document Title
2. A plain paragraph with some bold and some italic
3. Heading, level 1
4. Intense quote
5. first item in unordered list
6. first item in ordered list

---

```
import docx, readDocx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(' ' + para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

print(readDocx.getText('demo.docx'))
```

**Output:**

```
Document Title
A plain paragraph with some bold and some italic
Heading, level 1
Intense quote
first item in unordered list
first item in ordered list


Document Title
A plain paragraph with some bold and some italic
Heading, level 1
Intense quote
first item in unordered list
first item in ordered list
```

And this file appeared, 
[image]

I deleted this file and when rerun the program its been created again in the folder name **pycache**

Comment: no idea. what is `import readDocx` and why are you posting a same named function but not using it? Please change your code to a  [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the content in the document and what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Assuming that the module from your question is the readDocx you import in line 2: Don't import it; just use `print(getText('demo.docx'))` and consider putting your print function into a `__name__ == '__main__'` block

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, you seem to be importing the module that you are executing.
The code example in https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/ (somewhere in the middle) looks exactly like your getText() function and is mentioned to be saved to a file readDocx.py

While importing, all the code in the imported module is executed. The import line already executes your file, including the print().

Please try it without the readDocx in the import statement and consider familiarizing yourself with the aforementioned `__name__ == '__main__'` blocks

Comment: In other words, a module importing itself is both confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: Oh! my bad, I got the solution, I was thinking too complicated and trying different methods that are unnecessary when its very simplistic and easy. Sorry all for the miscommunication and misguiding the question itself.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with the docx or readDocx imports but as mentioned by Patrick in the comments you have a definition with the same name as what your calling in the print line.

ie:
You have defined getText() but then are using it as a function under readDocx.

Does readDocx have getText in its library?
Try changing the name of your getText definition to something else, and try a different document to see if you get the same result.

Comment: Updated the question please check!

Comment: You haven't reacted to the question and suggestion in the above answer. We need to know if it is your getText that is being run, or something else.